# Division in assembly program

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm, division

this is my code :

```
section .bss            ;Uninitialized data

average resb 5
num1 resb 5
num2 resb 5
num3 resb 5

section .text


global _start                ; make the main function externally visible


_start:

;User prompt

mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, messaging
mov edx, lenmessaging
int 0x80


;Read and store the user input

mov eax, 3
mov ebx, 0
mov ecx, num1
mov edx, 5       ;5 bytes (numeric, 1 for sign) of that information
int 0x80

mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, messaging
mov edx, lenmessaging
int 0x80

;Read and store the user input

mov eax, 3
mov ebx, 0
mov ecx, num2
mov edx, 5       ;5 bytes (numeric, 1 for sign) of that information
int 0x80

mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, userMsg
mov edx, lenUserMsg
int 0x80

;Read and store the user input

mov eax, 3
mov ebx, 0
mov ecx, num3
mov edx, 5       ;5 bytes (numeric, 1 for sign) of that information
int 0x80

;Output the message

mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, dispMsg
mov edx, lenDispMsg
int 0x80


; moving the first number to eax register and second number to ebx
; and subtracting ascii '0' to convert it into a decimal number

mov eax, [num1]
sub eax, '0'
mov ebx, [num2]
sub ebx, '0'

; add eax and ebx

add eax, ebx
mov ebx, [num3]
sub ebx, '0'
add eax, ebx


mov     bl, '3'
sub     bl, '0'
div     bl
add eax, '0'
mov [average], eax


;Output the number entered

mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, average
mov edx, 5
int 0x80

;////////////////

mov eax, 0x1              ; system call number for exit
sub esp, 4                ; OS X (and BSD) system calls needs "extra space" on stack
int 0x80                  ; make the system call


section  .data ;Data segment

userMsg db 'Please enter a number: ' ;Ask the user to enter a nu
lenUserMsg equ $-userMsg             ;The length of the message
dispMsg db 'The average is : '
lenDispMsg equ $-dispMsg
messaging db 'Enter another number : '
lenmessaging equ $-messaging
```

when I run it ,I have this error :

[image: screenshot]

how can I fix it?
this program is for calculating the average of three numbers.
thanks ;)

Comment: `bss` is not uninitialized data! It is cleared to zero on program startup. Perhaps you meant `data` instead?

Comment: bss is for uninitialized data !!

Comment: See the first paragraph on the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss) if you don't believe me ;-)

Comment: 1) You need to clear `ah` before `div bl`. 2) Your method of converting the input strings to integers doesn't look like it would work for anything except single-digit numbers.

Comment: everything is going OK on this program except division.

Comment: By "clear" I mean setting it to 0.